# Node.js: how to serve /index.html for all URLs?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node.js and I'd like to serve /index.html for all URLs.

For example, I'd like to serve /index.html for all these:

> ```
> foo.com
> foo.com/index.html
> foo.com/bling
> foo.com/blah/index.html
> ```

If possible I'd prefer not to change the URL displayed by the browser.

Is this possible and, if so, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, for example, express.js MVC npm module

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Saw your answer too late, posted almost the same myself :) `res.sendfile('index.html')` would be the easiest way to serve `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I now realise an obvious complication... I want to serve files included in /index.html as they are: CSS, JavaScript and images. How can I exclude these paths, i.e. all paths under /css, /js, /images, etc.?

Comment: @SamDutton Of course, use  `app.use(express.static(pathToYourStaticFiles));`

Comment: Thanks (again). So now I've got the following, which works for serving index.html, but gives mime type errors for the other files:  

`app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile("index.html");
}); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));`

How can I ensure the static files are served with the correct mime type?

Comment: @zavg Sorry -- still not clear how to serve static files other than /index.html: getting mime-type errors for my .js and.css.

Comment: @SamDutton Change the order of your statements `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js')); app.all('*', function(req, res){ res.sendfile("index.html"); });`. It is important.

Comment: @zavg -- thanks for that, but still getting .js files served as text/html with this statement order.

Answer (score 0):

Without express, and if it's the only task your server has to do, you might use the `fs` module in your `http` server instance main callback, piping a readStream to the response this way:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    fs.createReadStream('index.html', {
        'bufferSize': 4*1024
    }).pipe(response);
});
```